# Null analysis failing to understand code

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, code-analysis

I'm currently having issues with null analysis on both Eclipse and IntelliJ where they don't understand a piece of code that handles null pointer exceptions. Basically I got the method below:

```
@Nullable
public static <T> T getValueOrNull(Supplier<T> resolver) {
    try {
        T result = resolver.get();
        return Optional.ofNullable(result).orElse(null);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) { 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Normally I wouldn't catch those types of exceptions but in the project I'm working this method makes things much more readable.
It is called this way:

`getValueOrNull(() -> obj.getObj2().getObj3()...getObjN())`

This call returns the value or null if anything is null in the chain. 
The problem is that null analysis will complain about possible null pointer exceptions while calling the method. While it is true that any of them may be null the method is handling that error. Is there a way to either skip null analysis for the parameters of a method or help the analyzer understand what is happening?

It seems that even a very simple test where null pointer exceptions are being caught still flags potential null issues inside the try block. That makes me think that try catch blocks are never even considered by the analyzer.

Also I do know that there are other ways of doing this such as the code below but if possible I'd like to be able to use what we are currently doing due to readability. Also even the code below has issues with the null analysis for the IDEs mentioned above.

```
Optional.ofNullable(objectA)
.map(a -> a.getObjectB())
.map(b -> b.getObjectC())
.map(c -> c.getObjectD())
.map(d -> d.getObjectE())
.map(e -> e.getName())
.orElse("");
```

Comment: Where do you call `getValueOrNull`? That's likely where the problem is happening.

Comment: What if you use a custom supplier interface that `throws NullPointerException`?

Comment: Side note: `Optional.ofNullable(result).orElse(null)` seems entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @shmosel Yes the one above would be unnecessary. Even with the custom one the analyzer doesn't seem to realize that a null exception is being caught. It may just be because it is not supported since this is normally an anti pattern.